# Error adding table of contents to document in Lyx

Tags: lyx

when i add the table of contents to Lyx it gives me an error(right side of picture) and it adds that 29 in one page. If i add a Part III it will appear like 29Part III too. I've tried writing it in Tex too but the same error occurs. Can you help me?[image]

Here is the mwe .lyx file.  [HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-xqHeWZuqTgP9R4hLTroYGVtAZ-BZvyT)

Comment: You might be more likely to get help if you add a mwe .lyx file. For more information, see: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

You somehow managed to add a `\newpage` inside a `\paragraph`. This causes an error in the *.toc file. Just delete those new pages at the end of your file, under section 4. »Sistema...«.